# Hero image not centered

Tags: html, css, flexbox, background-image

I have this code pen:
[Code Pen](https://codepen.io/mugas/full/MWjPzMw)

But it seems that the image is not centered when I reduce the screen size but should not be  centering like this:

```css
.hero {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 90vh;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  background: url("./assets/hero2.png");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
}
```

and my HTML

```html
<section class="hero">
      <h1 id="header">
        Vuokrausasemalla asukkaiden tarvitsemat tavarat ja laitteet yhteiskäyttöön
      </h1>
      <article class="hero-header">
        <p>Parannamme elämänlaatua kasvattamatta hiilijalanjälkeä. Säästämme taloyhtiön asukkaiden kaappitilaa, rahaa ja aikaa tekemällä vuokraamisesta omistamista helpompaa.</p>
      </article>
     
        <form action="submit" class="hero-footer">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Sähköposti">
          <button>Tilaa uutiskirje</button>
        </form>
      
    </section>
```

Should work? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to specify `background-size` to cover both on `x` and `y`:
`background-size: cover cover;`.

This way, you're sacrificing the image edges to fully cover all axes of the container no matter the screen size.

Comment: Just did that now, yes it gives another perspective and it might be better. Thank you Lukas

Answer (score 1):

The screw pointing up in the background seems to stay in the center regardless of what size my window is. Maybe try a different browser? It works for me in the latest chrome and firefox.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you are right. I tried with one pic first and was working great and with this one just seem..off but yeah the center is the screw point. Thank you